# Pointer to an array of pointers, each being able to hold an object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am struggling with a CSC assignment right now. I can't understand what this is supposed to mean:

*videoGamesArray – a pointer to an array of pointers.  Each pointer in the array should be able to point to (hold the memory address of) an individual Video game object.*

I have a VideoGameLibrary class, which should hold VideoGame objects, which is another class. However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to incorporate the pointer to an array of pointers.

VideoGameLibrary class:

```
class VideoGameLibrary {
    
public:
    VideoGameLibrary** videoGamesArray;
    int maxGames;
    int numGames;
    
    VideoGameLibrary() {
        VideoGameLibrary* createGames(int);
    }
    ~VideoGameLibrary() {
        VideoGameLibrary* destroyGames(VideoGame*);
    }
    
    int getMaxGames();
    int getNumGames();
    
};
```

VideoGame class:

```
class VideoGame {
    
public:
    Text* gameTitle;
    Text* gamePlatform;
    int gameYear;
    Text* gameGenre;
    Text* ageRating;
    Text* userRating;
    
    VideoGame() {
        VideoGame* createVideoGame(Text*, Text*, int, Text*, Text*, int);
    }
    ~VideoGame() {
        void destroyVideoGame(VideoGame*);
    }
    
    Text* getVideoGameTitle();
    
};
```

However, once I've created a videoGame object, I am supposed to dynamically allocate it into the VideoGameLibrary class/array of pointers. I also have to find a way to check if the number of maxGames has been hit and if it has, then I create a new VideoGameLibrary and reallocate it with double the size and all of the old objects into the new one. Hopefully this makes sense.

```
void addVideoGameToArray() {
    Text* title;
    Text* platform;
    Text* genre;
    Text* ageRating;
    int year;
    int userRating;
    char tempStr[200];
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << right << setw(30) << "Video Game TITLE: " << left;
    cin.getline(tempStr, 200);
    title = createText(tempStr);
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << right << setw(30) << "Video Game PLATFORM: " << left;
    cin.getline(tempStr, 200);
    platform = createText(tempStr);
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << right << setw(30) << "Video Game YEAR: " << left;
    cin >> year;
    cin.ignore();
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << right << setw(30) << "Video Game GENRE: " << left;
    cin.getline(tempStr, 200);
    genre = createText(tempStr);
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << right << setw(30) << "Video Game AGE RATING: " << left;
    cin.getline(tempStr, 200);
    ageRating = createText(tempStr);
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << right << setw(30) << "Video Game USER RATING: " << left;
    cin >> userRating;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;
    
    VideoGame* game = createVideoGame(title, platform, year, genre, ageRating, userRating);
    
}
```

^ This is my function to create a VideoGame object. I'm stuck at adding it to the array.

Comment: When you write code, it behooves you to develop new functionality *in isolation* as much as possible. Before you attempt an array of pointers to `VideoGame`, try to implement an array of pointers to `int`.

Comment: Tip: In C++ you want to stay away from bare pointers, and you doubly want to stay away from double pointers. If you need to share data, consider wrappers like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Steer towards things like `std::vector` whenever possible. If this assignment forces you to use pointers, then alas you're stuck with a "C++" course that misses the point, but there's ways of surviving if you're careful.

Comment: Why are you declaring functions(?) inside your constructors? Why don't your constructors take arguments for the properties you're likely to set when constructing?

Comment: Also **use `std::string`** as C strings are a world of hurt, suffering and misery you do not want to experience. Managing buffers and avoiding buffer overflows is non-stop pain.

Comment: It sounds like they want `VideoGame* videoGamesArray`, not double pointers, especially not pointers to yourself.

Comment: Do I want to know what `Text*` is, or is ignorance bliss?

Comment: @tadman No, they want me to have double pointers. My professor specifically pointed this out.

Comment: Maybe your "C++" professor can better explain why, as that's an array of arrays, effectively, which is N+1 times more hassle than a 1D array. Courses like this tend to be completely orthogonal to any sort of C++ code you'd write in the real world. It's like a parallel universe full of confusion.

Comment: Regardless of the constraints you're given, it usually helps to *separate your concerns*, as in make each function have a very specific and deliberately narrow responsibility. `addVideoGameToArray()` takes input *and* creates an object. It should do one or the other, not both. Splitting things up like this makes each function way easier to test since it has less code to test, and more predictable inputs and outputs.